# Arduino sensor data

Tags: arduino, sensors

Hi I am using an Arduino Flex sensor to control a video game character.
The sensor data is being averaged and remapped to a value of between 0-6.
When the player flexes their bicep it reads the max value (this is perfect) however if the player flexes their arm hard and the sensor reads a max value of 6 for some reason as the player relaxes their arm the declining flex values are being passed into the game engine (instead of going from 6 to zero it drops from 6 to 5 to 4 to 3 to 2 to 1 before reaching zero). Can someone please advise how I should alter my code to make the sensor reading return to 0 instead of declining gradually?

```c
#define NUM_LED 6  //sets the maximum numbers of LEDs
#define MAX_Low 75 //for people with low EMG activity
#define MAX_High 150//for people with high EMG activity
#define Threshold 3 // this sets the light to activate TENS
int reading[10];
int finalReading;
int MAX = 0;
int TENS =3;
int ledState = LOW;  
byte litLeds = 0;
byte multiplier = 1;
byte leds[] = {8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13};
char ch; 
char contact; 

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600); //begin serial communications
  digitalWrite(TENS, LOW); 

  for(int i = 0; i < NUM_LED; i++){ //initialize LEDs as outputs
  pinMode(leds[i], OUTPUT);
  pinMode(TENS, OUTPUT); // Set TENS output to StimPin
  }
  MAX = MAX_High; //This sets the default to people with high EMG activity.
}


void loop(){ 

  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){    //take ten readings in ~0.02 seconds
    reading[i] = analogRead(A0) * multiplier;
    delay(2);
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){   //average the ten readings
    finalReading += reading[i];
  }
  finalReading /= 10;
  for(int j = 0; j < NUM_LED; j++)
  {  
    digitalWrite(leds[j], LOW);//write all LEDs low and stim pin low
  }

  finalReading = constrain(finalReading, 0, MAX);
  litLeds = map(finalReading, 0, MAX, 0, NUM_LED);
  Serial.println(litLeds);

  for(int k = 0; k < litLeds; k++){
  digitalWrite(leds[k], HIGH); // This turns on the LEDS 
                           }
     {
        // send data only when you receive data:
        if (Serial.available() > 0) 
        {
                ch = Serial.read();
                contact=digitalRead(TENS);
                if (ch == 'A' && contact==LOW)
                  {
                      digitalWrite(TENS, HIGH);
                    }

        else if (ch == 'B' && contact==HIGH)
              {  
                digitalWrite(TENS, LOW); 
              }      
        }
}

   delay(80);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sensor doesn't read 6 and immediately 0, you are reading it so fast that you can read the intermediate values. For example: if player opens the arm very fast (250-300 ms, it is fast), you can take up to 3 readings then you can read 3 intermediate values.
You can add more time to the last `delay()` or use only a value that is the same that the 3 last readings to ensure that there isn't a fast change.

Comment: If I use a longer delay it causes the Unity game engine to freeze for a second....I don't think a delay like that is an option. Can you give more details on this advice as I don't fully understand:
"....or use only a value that is the same that the 3 last readings to ensure that there isn't a fast change...."

Comment: If you read '1-2-3-4-5-6-6-6', don't send anything until you had read third '6' or something similar. The idea, storing the last N reading and comparing it; N equals or minimal variation between them...

Comment: Could anyone advise as to how I would script a piece of code which would select the highest value between once the flex sensor is activated and when it returns back to zero again ? ie. if the results from a flex were:0-1-2-3-4-5-6-4-2-0' how would I use a for loop to always choose the highest reading ?

Comment: int lastRead, maxReading = -1;
setup[...]
loop(){
//read
if(finalReading == 0){
    //Send reading
    maxReading = -1;
}
if(finalReading < maxReading){
    maxRead = finalReading;
}

}